# Given $x,y,z≥0 , x²+y²+z² = 7$ and $xy+yz+zx = 4$ , let maximum value of $xyz=&$. Find $3(&)^(2/3)$

Tags: inequality

I tried using comparison between Quadratic and Harmonic means that gave me a solution but when I checked for putting my answers it was written that 2 digit answer is acceptable. And my answer came somewhere irrational

Qm ≥ Hm :

$$\sqrt{(x²+y²+z²)/3}\ge 3/(1/x + 1/y + 1/z)$$

Putting values
$$\sqrt{7/3} \ge 3xyz/4$$

Comment: Here's a [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial :)

Comment: I can't even tell what the question is to even try to edit it

Comment: @JeanMarie Probably OP has abbreviated the expression Quadratic Mean.

Comment: @YNK Thanks.  I should have guessed...

Comment: Sorry for not writing the full forms, qm is quadratic mean or many of the population tells this as root mean square

Comment: I have got the answer so what should I do now I should delete the question or left it out. I got through simple am - gm and I think everybody knows am gm

Comment: $omkar Don't delete. Leave it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Since $(x+y+z)^2-8=7,$ we obtain $x+y+z=\sqrt{15}$ and $x$, $y$ and $z$ they are three non-negative roots of the equation:
$$t^3-\sqrt{15}t^2+4t=xyz.$$
But $$(t^3-\sqrt{15}t^2+4t)'=0$$ gives $t_{max}=\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt3}$ and the maximal value of $xyz$ it's
$$\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt3}\right)^3-\sqrt{15}\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+4\cdot\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt3}=\frac{2(1+\sqrt5)}{3\sqrt3}$$ and
$$3\left(\frac{2(1+\sqrt5)}{3\sqrt3}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=2\sqrt[3]{3+\sqrt5}$$

Answer (score 0):

By $uvw$ the expression $abc$ gets a maximal value for equality case of two variables. Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

Lagrange's multiplers method with two multipliers:

Maximize $xyz$ subject to contraints $x+y+z=\sqrt{15}$ & $x^2+y^2+z^2=7$.

We have the system (1) $yz=\lambda+\mu x$ (2) $xy=\lambda+\mu y$ (3) $xy=\lambda+\mu z.$

Substracing (2) from (1) we have $$z(y-x)=-\mu(y-x).$$
We have two cases:

(i) x=y. So, two variables are equal.

(ii) $z=-\mu$: Then (2) and (3) gives $x(y+\mu)=-\mu(y+\mu)$. So either $y=-\mu=z$ or $x=-\mu=z$. Two variables must be equal.

Can you continue?

The and will be $$3\left[\left(\frac{\sqrt5-1}{\sqrt3}\right)^2\left(\frac{\sqrt5 +2}{\sqrt3}\right)\right]^{\frac23}.$$